# Error while trying to display only certain colour pixels of an image that is captured

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to convert all the pixels of a captured image, that are not in the color yellow to white.

The error message that I am getting is:

```
if jmg[i,j]!=[255,255,0]:
valueError: the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. use a.any() or a.all()
```

Below is my code:

```
import cv2
import picamera
import numpy
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
print("ready")
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution=(400,400)
    time.sleep(1)
    camera.capture("/home/pi/rowdy.jpg")
    print("Done")
yellow=[255,255,0]
img=cv2.imread("/home/pi/rowdy.jpg",1)
jmg=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
for i in numpy.arange(399):
  for j in numpy.arange(399):
      if jmg[i,j]!=[255,255,0]:
          jmg[i,j]=[255,255,255]

plt.imshow(jmg)
plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can use the numpy library for speeding up the operation. Have a look at the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jmg` is a numpy array of three values. When you compare a numpy array to another array (or list, in your case), it will compare them `element-wise`.

```
if jmg[i,j]!=[255,255,0]: #np.array(255, 0, 0) != [255,255,0]
                          # -> np.array(False, True, False)
```

This means that you need to do what the error message says and use either `any()` or `all()` to determine the value you want. In your case, you want to check if `any` of those values don't match, which means your element-wise logic would make one of the three values `True`

```
if (jmg[i,j]!=[255,255,0]).any():
          jmg[i,j]=[255,255,255]
```

Answer (score 1):

A much faster way is to use the `numpy` library. First create a copy of the mage and then using `numpy.argwhere` replace the pixel values at the required positions:

```
image1 = image.copy()
image1[np.argwhere(image != [255,255,0])] = [255,255,255]
```

Comment: Thanks ,I will try it.